# Facebook ProfilePictureView : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getId()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio

I'm trying to get the profile picture for a facebook profile (mine).
Here is my android_manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fr.djey.***" >
    <!--android:name=".MyApplication"-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In gradle.build I have:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
```

I have my facebook buttons in a fragment that I call in another xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="fr.djey.***.MainFragment">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/facebook_avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I give you my onSuccess in the fragment java:

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            ProfilePictureView FacebookAvatar = (ProfilePictureView) getView().findViewById(R.id.facebook_avatar);
            FacebookAvatar.setProfileId(profile.getId());

        }
```

My login with facebook works perfectly, but I try to get the profile picture and it doesn't work. My app stops when I'm logged in with facebook and I have in the logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getId()' on a null object reference
```

I see that the problem is the **FacebookAvatar.setProfileId(profile.getID());**
But I don't know how to do differently.

**OK It doesn't work with a fragment but works perfectly without**

**Any idea why it doesn't work with fragment?**

Comment: the same trouble... have you got any fix?

Comment: The problem has been solved just when I removed the fragment. With the same code, without fragment it works.

Comment: Still looking for why it doesn't work in fragment